# Storing value changes in Django DB

Tags: python, django

I am recording price history data in a Django model and would like to save the value whenever it changes vs. it's previously recorded value.

For example, if I check prices once a day I'd like the following...

```
Time | Price
1    | $10
2    | $10
3    | $12
4    | $15
5    | $15
```

to be recorded as...

```
Time | Price
1    | $10
3    | $12
4    | $15
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My models.py file

```
class PriceHistory(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_id)
```

My current code that stores ALL rows to the database (for each row of a dataframe that is updated with new prices daily)

```
ph, created = PriceHistory.objects.update_or_create(
    product_id=row.product_id,
    defaults={
       "timestamp": timezone.now(),
       "price": row.price_current,
    }
)
```

Comment: Just check if the price is the same as the latest one before saving the PriceHistory object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `get_or_create`? it will not create the new item if it already exists

```
obj, created = PriceHistory.objects.get_or_create(
    product_id=row.product_id,
    price=row.price_current,
    defaults={"timestamp": timezone.now()},
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if I filter for price & product then it will not record cases when the price returns to a historic value? Unless I am missing something!

Comment: What do you mean `price returns to a historic value`

Comment: In this example - [Day 1: $10; Day 2: $12; Day 3: $10]. The $10 on day 3 will not get saved